# Finding set $L$ of all left cosets of $Z$ in (R, +)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the set L of all left cosets of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the additive group ($\mathbb{R}$, +) of all real numbers is given by $L = \{x+\mathbb{Z}:0 \leq x < 1\}$. Here I can understand that $L = \mathbb{R}$. But how do I proceed  on this proof?

Comment: Consider an arbitrary element $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and try to argue that there is an integer $n$ such that $x-n\in [0,1)$. It can be validated in several ways. Remember also that $x+L=y+L$ if and only if $x-y\in L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition the cosets are precisely the sets of the form $y + \mathbb{Z}$: for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ is in the coset $[y] := y + \mathbb{Z}$ iff $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, it's enough to show that the collection $\{x + \mathbb{Z} : 0 \leq x < 1\}$ actually exhausts all the cosets. This is just showing that for all cosets $y + \mathbb{Z}$ there is some coset representative in $[0, 1)$, or equivalently, that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $x \in [0, 1)$ that differs from $y$ by some integer